# Zend - SELECT statement "AS"

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I have the following query

```
(select informed from evaluations where releases_id="1234") AS INFO
```

ZEND frameword query:

```
$get_details = $db->select()
                ->from(array('INFO'=>'evaluations'), 'informed')
                ->where('releases_id =?',"$row[id]");
```

The above gives

```
SELECT `INFO`.`informed` FROM `evaluations` AS `INFO` WHERE (releases_id ='1214')
```

but I would like to get

```
(select informed from evaluations where releases_id="1234") AS INFO
```

Can anyone please guide me to build the right query?

Comment: `(select informed from evaluations where releases_id="1234") AS INFO` - is it syntactically correct?

Comment: That's a subquery which I am going to include in the main query. However it executes perfectly on SQL browser

Comment: @zerkms, Query syntax is correct I suppose

Comment: "That's a subquery which I am going to include in the main query" --- you need to provide more details then. At the moment a query as it is doesn't look syntactically correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from your request :

```
$get_details = $db->select()
            ->from(array('INFO'=>'evaluations'), 'informed')
            ->where('releases_id =?',"$row[id]");
```

Try this to rename your subquery, it should work :

```
$get_details = $db->select()->from(array('INFO' => $get_details))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in Zend but you may try something along the lines of

```php
$subquery = $this->select()
    ->from('evaluations'), array('informed')) 
    ->where('releases_id = ?', $row[id]);

$main = $this->select()
    ->from('info' => new Zend_Db_Expr('(' . $subquery . ')'));

$result = $this->fetchAll($main);
```